# Are global variables in the SignalR server (C#.net) supposed to keep their values after different functions are called?

Tags: signalr

I have nearly completed my choose a number game with SignalR.  The program pairs up the users and allows them to play their individual games.  The one problem I am having is my global variables aren't keeping there values when they are changed in different functions.  After each function the variables take on the original values that they were initialized with.  I am wondering if this is normal?  If it isn't than I need to recreate the actual project and cut and paste my source code.  Do global variables in the SignalR server (C#.net) keep their values after different functions are called that use them?

My variables are members of the ChatHub class:

```
namespace SignalRChat.Hubs
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public String PlayerOneConnId = "10";
        public String PlayerTwoConnId = "10";
```

Comment: C# doesn't really have global variables - every variable is a class member of some sort.  Can you clarify what these global variables are (e.g. what class are they a member of? are they static?)

Answer (score 0):

It is normal when a SignalR function is over the declared variables do not maintain their values.  Hubs are transient.  I personally used my container and added variables to it.